# Opening an activity from Notification with PendingIntent after the App has been killed causing App to crash

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, android-service

I need to open an `Activity` by clicking on `Notification` (with `PendingIntent`) after the application has been killed. This is how I am setting `PendingIntent`.

```
var chatActivityIntent = new Intent (this, typeof(ChatActivity));
chatActivityIntent.PutExtra ("UUID", channelViewModel.uuid);
chatActivityIntent.PutExtra ("CHANNELSVIEWMODEL", JsonConvert.SerializeObject(channelViewModel.channelList [0]) );
chatActivityIntent.AddFlags (ActivityFlags.ClearTop | ActivityFlags.SingleTop | ActivityFlags.NewTask);
var pendingIntent = PendingIntent.GetActivity (this, 0, chatActivityIntent, 0);
notification.SetLatestEventInfo (this, chatviewModel.SchoolName, chatviewModel.Message, pendingIntent);
```

This works gracefully when the App is active or is in Background. `ChatActivity` opens up when I click the notification.

But after the App is killed, when I click on notification that has arrived, I get an error message `Unfortunately, App has stopped.`

Comment: Please post full LogCat, and exception that is thrown at that moment. You are probably depending on something that is not active.

Comment: This happens after I kill the App. Can I get LogCat or exception details after app gets killed ?

Comment: I dont think so, try to put general filter on logcat.

Comment: Is it because there was an attempt to Launch an activity by the notification which is not set as LaunchActivity ? Do I have to mention anything in Manifest to tell OS that this Activity can be invoked when App is not running

Comment: No, android does it automatically. It just recreates activity from scratch when you press notification. You probably get some error on initialization of activity, you MUST find that logcat.

Comment: Here is the Logcat http://pastebin.com/yXQEnMDR . From that it seems to be like I am trying to access a member of Service before it gets bound in OnResume of my Activity. I will get back here if I have got any clue. Thank You @DjDexter5GHz

Comment: @DjDexter5GHz It was that I was trying to call a method in Service from the Activity before the service was getting bound. Thank you